# My error using AWS CDK is that my build is failing due to 'No stacks match the name(s) -nameofstack-'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Im very new to AWS.This is my first time using CDK and making my first lambda and dynamoDB.

My first build was successful, and made no changes other than setting up dynamoDB. There are no red errors acccording to the IDE I am using but I am unable to see my DynamoDB resource in the AWS Console.

Here is the error 'No stacks match the name(s) examplename' when I deploy it.

Where can I look? and what commands can I run to verify that the names of the stacks match up?

Comment: Can you update your thread and specify the command you ran and specify the order

Comment: Please share: full error message, CDK version.

If you're able to post the full CDK code, it would also be nice.

Answer (score -5):

there was a mismatch in the deployment file. I got my error fixed.

Comment: would be great to learn in as few words as possible what the mismatch was - typo, confused choice of stack, more - to assist the next hitting this issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).